# How to reset hidden posts which needed moderator attention?

Tags: support

I hidden a few posts which were brought to my attention and that needed moderation. I am talking about posts found on https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/review

How can I unhide them or reset all my hidden posts?

Comment: Hi Peter, do you mean to say that you "skipped" them? If so, I think they do come back after some time. If that's not what you mean, let me know and I'll do some digging.

Comment: Yes, skipped posts :). The message on posts needing moderation irritates me and I want to unhide those posts and review them again.

Comment: @jmort253 Hey did you find anything?

Comment: I'm asking around, but I suspect the answer could be that the review items have simply been handled by other users. There's only about 4 items in there right now. Also, I've heard the counter is heavily cached. I personally only see 3 actual items to review, even though the counter says 4. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what to say about the counter. It seems buggy to me. Yesterday it showed 21, and couple of hours after that it showed like 5 or 6.